# Why Isn't my page being fully viewed in Firefox but it is in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

So my website shows the images in google chrome but not in firefox! Anyone who can help? It only shows the background image in firefox! I've tried many things but nothing works for me. Anyone who can help :D

website: http://z16-zacho.it.slotshaven.dk/html/index.html

```
   body {
    background-color: transparent;
    color:saddleBrown;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
h1, h2 {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgb(176, 184, 196);
    border-radius: 100px;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 6px;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
h3 {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-size: 24px;
}
p {
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgb(176, 184, 196);
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 6px;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.9;
    color: black;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
span {
    color: rgb(16, 140, 206);
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: -3px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}
li {
    float: left;
    border-right:1px solid #bbb;
}
li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
    float: right;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}
.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
} 
#boks1 {
    max-width: 48%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0.5%;
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: purple;
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#boks2 {
    max-width: 48%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0.5%;
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: purple;
    float: right;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#background {
    background-image: url(../billeder/background.jpg);
    min-height: 500px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
#img-me {
    content: url(../billeder/billede_af_mig.jpg);
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
#head {
    content: url(../billeder/head.png);
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    background-color: rgb(238, 242, 254);
    height: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    float: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
#facebook {
    content: url(../billeder/fb.png);
    width: 16px;
}
#instagram {
    content: url(../billeder/instagram.png);
    width: 16px;
}
#twitter {
    content: url(../billeder/twitter.png);
    width: 20px;
}
#snapchat {
    content: url(../billeder/snap.png);
    width: 16px;
}
#normalP {
    font-size: 16;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    border-style: none;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 0px;   
    opacity: 1;
    color: black;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="../css/frontpageStyle.css"  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Zacool site</title>
</head>
<body>
    <body id="background"></body>
    <header>
        <a href=" (link here was url shortened so i removed it) " target="_blank">
        <div id="head"></div>
        </a>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Forside</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Min valgfrie ting</a></li>
        <li><a href="kronik.html">Kronik</a></li>
        <li><a id="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/tobias.zacho" target="_blank"></a></li>
        <li><a id="instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com/tobiaszacho99/" target="_blank"></a></li>
        <li><a id="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/Tobi1790?lang=da" target="_blank"></a></li>
        <li><a id="snapchat" href="snap.html" target="_blank"></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://slotshaven.dk/" target="_blank">Slotshaven</a></li>
    </ul>
    </header>
    <h1>Velkommen! Denne side er kodet af <span id="header-shadow">Tobias Zacho</span></h1>
        <div id="img-me"></div>
        <p>&#8595 <span>Scroll ned for mere info</span> &#8595</p>
    <body>
        <div id="background"></div>
        <div style="height:0px;background-color:transparent;"><!-- Lavet så man får scrolling effekten! --></div>
    </body> 
    <div id="boks1">
        <h3>
        Hvem er jeg?
        </h3>
        <p id="normalP">
        Test
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="boks2">
        <h3>
        Overskrift
        </h3>
        <p id="normalP">
        Test
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if it is related, but your code has 3 different `<body>` tags, one with an ID "background" inside the main one and another below the `<header>` tag. Refrain from using multiple `<html>`, `<head>` or `<body>` tags as things might not work properly

Comment: It didn't work but came to mind that it's the reason I'm able to make the scroll on the front page :D

Comment: I tested it and your website is working on both chrome and firefox for me. So I don't really know what's the issue haha

Comment: Well for me there is a different

Comment: Chrome --> https://gyazo.com/27b4311365305afe36ba8ca53c46af70

Firefox --> https://gyazo.com/febdd70ecc2418e42fe24f42d9d51895

Comment: you have <body id="background"></body> but you don't close the body there. take out </body>

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `#head` on your CSS:

```
#head {
    background-image: url(../billeder/head.png);
    background-color: rgb(238, 242, 254);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 15vh; /* 15% of the screen's height */
}
```

The way you set it, it doesn't have a defined height, and different browsers interpret that in different ways.

Also, a thing to note: on small width screens, that header image looks quite small. Try cutting a bit of that whitespace on the .png to give it some space!

And lastly, this is *one* solution to it. If you're ever unsatisfied, there surely are other ways to accomplish what you're looking for!

Comment: Thanks for your time, it works. Going to chance the rest now, again very much appreciate it :D

Comment: @Tobias, if this answer worked for you please mark it as the correct answer :-)